# c++ indexed container with o(1) lookup

Tags: c++, indexing, find, dataset, containers

I am going to store char's in some container, then take char's from a string and look up index for char from string in said container.
I also need to do the opposite, take an index and find out what char is there.

So it be more like:

```
container<char> c;
int index = c.indexOf('a');
char letter = c[12];
```

I don't care about insert or remove operations.

I suppose the best solution would be to just use a string or char table.
Then do:

```
int index = 'a'-myString[0]; //for lookup
char c = myString[index];    //for index
```

Comment: Look up for what?

Comment: Did you do any research at all before posting this?

Comment: How about `map` and `unordered_map`?

Comment: Yes, I have been doing some research and trying out different things. Map isn't going to help me, I can declare a map<char key, int index> and looking up by key will be quick. But finding what key is behind an index will be slow.

Set does not seem to meet my expectations either. It sounds like a job for a hashtable?

Comment: @AleksanderNaumenok that should be part of the question, not just a comment. What about two maps? Then you have fast lookup in both directions

Comment: What is the domain ie possible values of `char`'s you want to store?

Comment: @gustavsehgal I suppose those will depend on ascii table.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The generic data structure that has the ability to look up in two directions is the bidirectional map. If implemented with hash tables, it should have constant complexity for lookup.

Now, if we can make the assumption that `char` is 8 bits wide, and that your indices are contiguous, then we can use a greatly simpler data structure: Simply store the characters in an array. Use another array of size `1 << CHAR_BIT` to store the index of each character.